# R, JAGS and missing data

Tags: bayesian, jags

I am currently using JAGS via the program R to run N-mixture models using about 5 years of count data.  In 3 of these years, there were 3 counts per site, while in the remaining 2 there were 2 counts per site.  Using pcount in the package unmarked didn't generate any problems with these data.  However, I need to use a program that would allow me to model random effects.  I know WinBUGS allows for missing data, however my models are rather large and WinBUGS ran for about 2 weeks without any success.  Using JAGS, I've been able to run the models on each set of data, however can't figure out how to run them together.  I've seen previous posts suggest that JAGS requires you to impute missing data, but it doesn't make sense to me to impute the count data itself.  Also missing are visit level covariates (e.g. Time1 and Time2 are available for the data from the last 2 years, however Time 3 - while present in the first 3 years - is not available because there was no third count.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks
KC

```
kc.model<-function(){
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Abundance site and detection site random effects
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
for (i in 1:7315){
eps[i] ~ dnorm(0, tau.lam) # Abundance noise
}
tau.lam <- 1 / (sd.lam * sd.lam)
sd.lam ~ dunif(0, 3)

for (i in 1:7315){
    teta.p[i]~dnorm(0,tau.p)
}
tau.p <- 1 / (sd.p * sd.p)
sd.p ~ dunif(0.01, 0.99)


# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#Priors
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
a0 ~ dnorm(0, 0.01)
a1 ~ dnorm(0, 0.01)
a2 ~ dnorm(0, 0.01)
a3 ~ dnorm(0, 0.01)
a4 ~ dnorm(0, 0.01)
a5 ~ dnorm(0, 0.01)
a6 ~ dnorm(0, 0.01)
a7 ~ dnorm(0, 0.01)
a8 ~ dnorm(0, 0.01)
a9 ~ dnorm(0, 0.01)
a10 ~ dnorm(0, 0.01)
a11 ~ dnorm(0, 0.01)

b0 ~ dnorm(0, 0.01)
b1~ dnorm(0, 0.01)
b2~ dnorm(0, 0.01)
b3~ dnorm(0, 0.01)
b4~ dnorm(0, 0.01)
b5~ dnorm(0, 0.01)
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

for(i in 1:7315) {
    N[i] ~ dpois(lambda[i])
    log(lambda[i]) <- a0 + a1*PE[i] +a2*PE2[i] +a3*PC[i] + a4*WAJuly[i] +    
a5*PropSeas[i] + a6*logWA[i] + a7*SEMIPERM[i] + a8*TEMP[i] + 
    a9*SEMIPERM[i]*PropSeas[i] + a10*TEMP[i]*PropSeas[i]+ a11*PC[i]*PropSeas[i] + 
eps[i]

    for(j in 1:3) {
        logit(p[i, j]) <- b0 +
b1*TIME[i,j]+b2*PE[i]+b3*WA[i]+b4*TIME2[i,j]+b5*LogDate[i]+teta.p[i]
        y[i, j] ~ dbin(p[i, j], N[i])

eval[i,j]<-p[i,j]*N[i]
E[i,j]<-pow((y[i,j] - eval[i,j]),2)/(eval[i,j]+0.5)
y.new[i,j]~dbin(p[i,j],N[i])
E.new[i,j]<-pow((y.new[i,j] - eval[i,j]),2) / (eval[i,j] + 0.5) 
        }
    }
fit <- sum(E[,])
fit.new <- sum(E.new[,]) 
}

N<-7315 

jagsData<-list(y=as.matrix((df8[,c("C1","C2","C3")])),
    PE=as.numeric(as.vector(df8$PE)),
  PE2=as.numeric(as.vector(df8$PE2)),
    WA=as.numeric(as.vector(df8$Swetarea)),
  LogDate=as.numeric(as.vector(df8$LSdate)),
    SEMIPERM=as.numeric(as.vector(df8$SEMIPERM)),
  TEMP=as.numeric(as.vector(df8$TEMP)),
    WAJuly=as.numeric(as.vector(df8$Swetareajuly)),
  PropSeas=as.numeric(as.vector(df8$SPropSeas)),
    PC=as.numeric(as.vector(df8$PC)),
  logWA=as.numeric(as.vector(df8$logWA)),
    TIME=as.matrix((df8[,c("time1","time2","time3")])),
    TIME2=as.matrix((df8[,c("time12","time22","time32")])))


jagsPars<-
c("a0","a1","a2","a3","a4","a5","a6","a7","a8","a9","a10","a11","b0","b1","b2","b3","
b4","b5","sd.lam","sd.p","fit","fit.new")
jagsInits<-function()
list(a0=runif(1),a1=runif(1),a2=runif(1),a3=runif(1),a4=runif(1),a5=runif(1),a6=runif
(1),a7=runif(1),a8=runif(1),a9=runif(1),
a10=runif(1),a11=runif(1),b0=runif(1),b1=runif(1),b2=runif(1),b3=runif(1),b4=runif(1)
,b5=runif(1),N=as.integer(rep(45,5175)),sd.lam = runif(1, 0, 1), sd.p = runif(1, 0,         
1))

set.seed(123)
system.time(out2<-
jags(jagsData,jagsInits,jagsPars,kc.model,n.chains=2,n.thin=1,n.iter=200,n.burnin=10
)
```

Count data appears as follows:
C1 C2 C3
1   1  1
1   0  1
1   2  NA
4   3  NA

All variables incorporated in the model that aren't categorical are standardized to zero.  The only other missing data is the visit level data "Time" and that's only missing for the C3 in the years where we didn't have a third count.   Thanks again.

Comment: Why doesn't it make sense to impute count data?

Comment: Maybe you could post more information on your data and the JAGS code? This would be helpful to understand your problem better. Generally JAGS has no problem with missing data: it simply replicates the NA's using your prior.